# Alternative for FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever

Tags: android, dependencies

Can anyone suggest an alternative for FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever in order to retrieve the metadata from live streaming Radio ? FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever library is increasing the APK file size to 25MB. Looking forward for earliest replies.Thanking you.

Answer (score 1):

Build individual APK's for each architecture, that's why FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever offers prebuilt AAR's for each type.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this approach is discouraged, and adds a lot of complexity to the development / update process.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Gradle has support for Product Flavors and Build Variants which is intended to simplify and streamline development for multiple architectures.

Comment: Sure, but in terms of maintaining multiple version numbers, and apks, it's certainly an overhead in comparison to a single apk.

Comment: Agreed, but you said the approach is "discouraged". When, in fact, most major companies use this exact approach. Thus, it is commonplace and nowhere does Google say it's discouraged.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html "we encourage you to develop and publish a single APK that supports as many device configurations as possible"

Comment: The full quote from the article, not the one you took out of context, is "Although we encourage you to develop and publish a single APK that supports as many device configurations as possible, doing so is sometimes not possible". Also, encouraging developers to follow one generalized practice is not the same as discouraging them from following others.

Comment: I posted a question regarding `FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever` pre-build `.aar`'s , I couldn't find any information about this, can you please have a look - https://stackoverflow.com/q/52253127/8199772